# Div following cursor paints pixels on screen in Safari (bug?)

Tags: javascript, css, safari, requestanimationframe

I've used the following code to make a div that follows the cursor with easing applied to the movement:

CSS

```
#cursor {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: opacity 200ms;
    cursor:none!important;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index:99999999;
    color:white;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).on("mouseover mousemove", function (event) {
    mouseX = event.pageX;
    mouseY = event.pageY - $(window).scrollTop();
    cursorWidth = $cursor.width();
    cursorHeight = $cursor.height();
});
requestAnimationFrame(performAnimation);

var performAnimation = function() {
        var distX = mouseX - cursorX;
        var distY = mouseY - cursorY;
        cursorX = cursorX + (distX * speed);
        cursorY = cursorY + (distY * speed);

        $cursor.css({
            left: cursorX + "px",
            top: cursorY + "px"
        });
    request = requestAnimationFrame(performAnimation)
}
```

It works as intended in Chrome, but on Safari it leaves traces of the text in the div on top of the screen, i. e. the elements underneath the cursor z-index wise. Here's a [video](https://streamable.com/k2ond) showing the behaviour.

Is this a known bug with Safari and can it be avoided somehow? I'm not sure if this has to do with the `requestAnimationFrame()` function or if it's something else. I tried applying `backface-visiblity:none;` to the `#cursor` itself through CSS, as this sometimes solves these type of issues, but in this case it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem had to do with the `#cursor` being a child of a container that was fixed on top of the whole page. Removing this container and placing `#cursor` without a container on it's own fixed the issue.

For some reason I thought it was practical to have the cursor wrapped in this container so that I could add classes through JS to the container instead of the cursor itself to manipulate it's style. But I ended up adding the styling classes to a `<span>` inside `#cursor` instead.